# Why is it allowed to overide non-virtual function?

Tags: c++, function, virtual

I'm experimneting with inheritance in C++.

```
struct A {
    virtual void foo(){ std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl; }
    void bar(){ std::cout << "bar()" << std::endl; }
};

struct B : A{
    void foo(){ std::cout << "derived foo()" << std::endl; }
    void bar(){ std::cout << "derived bar()" << std::endl; }
};

struct C : B {
    void foo(){ std::cout << "derived derived foo()" << std::endl; }
    void bar(){ std::cout << "derived derived bar()" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{

    B* b = new C();
    b->foo();  //derived derived foo()
    b->bar();  //derived bar()
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93196976b9004a42)

Since, the function `foo` declared as non-virtual in the `struct B` I expected that `B`'s function would be called. But `foo` which one from `C` was. Why? I change the "virtual status" of the function in `B`. Why is it still virtual?

Comment: `B::foo` is implicitly virtual since you've overwritten it. The keyword `virtual` is optional but recommended.

Comment: AFAIK decorating a function with `virtual` in the base-class means all sub-class implementations of that function are necessarily virtual. You cannot "go back" on making a function virtual in a base-class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foo()` is declared as virtual function in the base class `A`, so `foo()` in all the derived class will be virtual too.

From the standard, 10.3$2 Virtual functions [class.virtual] (bold by me)

> If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a
>   class Derived, derived directly or indirectly from Base, a member
>   function vf with the same name, parameter-type-list (8.3.5),
>   cv-qualification, and ref-qualifier (or absence of same) as Base::vf
>   is declared, then Derived::vf is also virtual (**whether or not it is so**
>   **declared**) and it overrides Base::vf.

Answer (score 2):

Once virtual always virtual.

Since `foo` is virtual in `A` it will be virtual in all classes derived from `A` - whether or not they get the `virtual` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Above mention answers are valid, but can we use `override` keyword, because

```
The override special identifier means that the compiler will check the
base class(es) to see if there is a virtual function with this exact
signature. And if there is not, the compiler will indicate an error.
```

so something like this is `struct B`:

```
void bar() override
```